# x86 assembly to get register as int?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, bit-manipulation

The portable way of accessing bits in the FP representation is to write into a union, which writes into memory.  At least, that's what glibc does.  But the code below looks wildly overcomplicated, as well as slow.  I'm wondering whether there is an x86 instruction to copy 64 accessible bits of an FP register into an integer register so that the bits can be manipulated?  This wouldn't be portable, but the idea is to have an inline function, and each port has to implement a standard clean (and fast) routine.

In this case I'm looking at isnan, which is implemented as:

```
#define EXTRACT_WORDS(ix0,ix1,d)                \
do {                            \
  ieee_double_shape_type ew_u;              \
  ew_u.value = (d);                     \
  (ix0) = ew_u.parts.msw;                   \
  (ix1) = ew_u.parts.lsw;                   \
} while (0)

int __isnan(double x)
{
    int32_t hx,lx;
    EXTRACT_WORDS(hx,lx,x);
    hx &= 0x7fffffff;
    hx |= (u_int32_t)(lx|(-lx))>>31;
    hx = 0x7ff00000 - hx;
    return (int)(((u_int32_t)hx)>>31);
}
```

Comment: An FP register is 80 bits wide, so won't fit in a normal register...

Comment: Note also that accessing the bits through a union is most definitely *not* portable.  The compiler intrinsics can get away with it because, by definition, they've been written for a specific platform.

Comment: Actually, the glibc code is portable.  it works for IEEE 754 math, which is a standard.  The 80 bit hardware isn't standard, yes.  I was curious whether one could extract the 64 bits, as you would do if you wrote to memory.

Comment: IEEE-754 does not specify, for instance, the endianness of the representation in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no x86 instruction to copy a FP register into an integer register or vice versa. You can probably get what you want by using SSE instrinsics instead, since an SSE register can contain both integer and floating point values.

Comment: is there a hardware test for "special" values like Nan and Inf?

Comment: @Dov, I don't think so. You can do a!=a for NaN and QNaN and probably compare directly against Inf or -Inf, but since those can be slow anyway, you might as well use the functions in math.h.